# Setup an Inbox in Outlook 2016 to not show unread emails

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

One of my inboxes at work is a general inbox which we do not regularly read. I need to have access to this inbox in case I need to direct a customer to send in documents or in case I need to trouble shoot an issue, however I do not generally care about emails in it (currently 546 unread emails).

Is there a way to prevent this inbox from flagging the unread icon in the tray and taskbar? I can't create a rule to mark all emails as read because that would conflict with the other people who use this inbox.

Comment: What about turning of the automatic Send/Receive for that folder? And only synchronizing it when you need it?

Comment: @derz00 I'd still have 500+ unread emails I'd rather not fiddle with. Some people use this inbox a lot more than I do for testing purposes and I'd want to do anything that effects the inbox on the exchange server.

Comment: How do you have access to it? Were you granted full mailbox access by your Exchange Administrator? Or were you given the login information?

Comment: @JoshuaShourds I have full permissions to the box. It's a standalone mailbox in Exchange which a number of techs share for misc. stuff. We try not to give our actual emails out to customers and we do a lot of troubleshooting connection and Exchange issues on it.

Comment: Version of Exchange?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Turn off the setting for showing the envelope notification on new mail arrival in Outlook's options. This is a *global* setting and affects all mailboxes to which you have access.
2. Create a rule that shows the envelope icon on new mail arrival, but set a condition to scope the rule to only your primary mailbox.
3. Enjoy.